# docker-compose.yml - Unable to connect to app via browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a beginner to the Docker world. I am currently using Docker Toolbox so please pardon me if I posted this question at the wrong section of the forum. Thanks

I was trying out all the steps in parts 1 and 2 of the tutorial without any major issues - I was able to deploy the friendlyhello app and access it by keying in  on my browser. However, the problem comes when I was trying part 4. After creating the docker-compose.yml and following the rest of the instructions, I was not able to access the app via my browser anymore with  or with the curl command. It says connection was refused. I have attached screenshot of all the commands as well as the error along with this post.

Any ideas where I have gone wrong? Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think about that the ip in curl command is wrong.

You can run in "cmd"

netstat -n | findstr 4000

It will show the IP address that is listening on 4000 port.

[consolresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fg74.jpg)

If you see 0.0.0.0 it's listening on all ip address so that you can try on localhost or 127.0.0.1 else use the specific address from result command.

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I realized I had to stop and remove containers that were running on port 4000 before I could run a new container. Hence, I went ahead and removed all images and containers before repeating the tutorial steps.

However, now I am receiving 'time out' error